# What are the difference among entire, smooth, analytic and holomorphic in complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

In complex analysis, I know that they have similar meaning.
However what are the difference among them? Especially for entire function, does entire function mean analytic function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"$f$ is holomorphic on $U$" means "the complex derivative of $f$ exists and is continuous on $U$".

"$f$ is entire" means means "$f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$".

"$f$ is smooth on $U$" means a lot of different things in different contexts. For complex analysis, let us introduce the map $p : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $p(x+iy)=(x,y)$. Then "$f$ is smooth on $U$" probably means that $p \circ f \circ p^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is infinitely differentiable on $p(U)$. (In other words, the underlying function on the plane, where we forget about complex numbers, is smooth.) This concept doesn't come up very often in complex analysis because you really need to work with holomorphic functions to use complex-analytic methods.

"$f$ is analytic on $U$" *a priori* means "a power series expansion of $f$ exists on $U$". It is a remarkable fact in complex analysis that this is *equivalent* to $f$ being holomorphic on $U$. As a result of this the two terms are sometimes used interchangeably. Another result of this is that holomorphic functions are smooth (in the sense of the previous paragraph).

Comment: +1 In case OP hasn't seen the difference, in (3), $f$ smooth means it is smooth as a function on the underlying $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is a much weaker condition than being analytic. For instance, $z\mapsto Re(z)$ is certainly smooth

Comment: @hunter Good point, let me edit that in.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ if the complex derivative exists at every point in $U$. The continuity of the derivative follows from that.

Comment: @MartinR If I remember correctly, you are right for open sets $U$. I just wanted to avoid technicalities.

Comment: Is a holomorphic map necessarily smooth?